# Can i leave the variables in struct undefined in c++?

Tags: c++

I have defined a struct like this

```
Struct rectangle{

int x;
int y;
int z;

};
```

and then in my main method, i will be assigning the variables:

```
void main(int argc, const char *argv[])

{

   for(i=0;i<20;i++)

   {

     rectangle[i].x = 20;
     rectangle[i].y = 10;

    }

}
```

But I wont be assigning the 'z' variable of the struct anytime. Am i allowed to do this?
hope i am not asking something very dumb!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  Any attempt to use `rectangle[i].z` will result in undefined behaviour,<sup>*</sup> but that's not a problem so long as you don't try to use it.

---

<sub>* Unless `rectangle` is declared as a global/static array, in which case all its members are implicitly initialized to zero.</sub>

Comment: The spec says reading an uninitialized object produces UB (4.1/1), but the spec also clearly says that z will be default initialized (8.5/11). Therefore I think the glvalue-prvalue conversion itself is not UB. So for example this should be well defined: `if (std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::trap == false) { unsigned x; unsigned y = x + x; }`. On the other hand doing the above with `int` could be UB, not because of 4.1/1, but because it might overflow, which causes UB for `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to do it. The member `z` will have an **indeterminate** value though.
So If you use it, without assigning any value to it you will end up with an **Undefined Behavior(UB)**.

However, If the structure object is an global or static object then `z` will be implicitly initialized to `0` and you do not have to bother about UB.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, it won't harm. You can even print rectangle[i].z's value to see what was here before on the stack :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get away without declaring `z` but the value for z will be undefined.

Think about using a default constructor for the struct and also defining `rectangle z` as a gloabal or static will initialize it to `0` so you don't have to worry about the value it will take on otherwise.